# MySQL how to make a backup while the server is not running

Tags: mysql, backup

I made a update on my mac to catalina few days ago. After this my MySQL-Server was broken and I would like to reinstall it. Before doing this I would like to make a backup of my database. Because the server is not running I can't use mysqldump or phpMyAdmin. Is it enough to save the directory /usr/local/mysql/data/ or is there anything else I should do?

Thanks Thomas

Comment: Saving the directory tree will at least let you get back to where you are now.

Answer (score 0):

You can take physical backup of mysql data directory.

Step-1 Take backup of mysql data directory.

```
cd /datadir/
cp -r /datadir/ /backup_path/
```

Step-2 Once you re-install it, just verify data are whether data are purged or not ?

Step-3 If data are not purged from datadir, Simple you need to start mysql service & ready go.

Step-4 Otherwise you are suppose to copy backup datadir from backup path.

```
cd /datadir/
cp -r  /backup_path/ /datadir/
```